# No module named 'xxx'; 'yyy' is not a package

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following structure:

```
Oracle    
| before_OOP  
| | dump_ora_shelve.py  
cOr.py
```

`get_users.py` retrieves the data from shelve "database" and works just fine:

```
def get_shelve_users(field):
    import shelve
    db = shelve.open('oracle-shelve')
    for key in db:
        if key == field:
             return db[key]
    db.close()
```

`cOr.py` has to have get_shelve_users to be imported:

```
 from Oracle.before_OOP.dump_ora_shelve import get_shelve_users
```

But when I call for an import (even if PyCharm can successfully find this folder and suggest me what I want to import) import doesn't work:

```
    from Oracle.before_OOP.dump_ora_shelve import get_shelve_users
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Oracle.before_OOP'; 'Oracle' is not a package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the import should look like this:

```
from before_OOP.dump_ora_shelve import get_shelve_users
```

Comment: why that and not from Oracle.before_OOP.dump_ora_shelve import get_shelve_users

Answer (score 1):

Add the location of Oracle to the environment variable PYTHONPATH.

If you are in the command line: `PYTHONPATH=. python cOr.py`